# Why JSON deserializer returns null value when JSON string is not empty?

Tags: json.net, jsonconvert

I am trying to deserialize the following string :

```
{"image":"c:\testimage\test.jpg","predictions":[[0.0000103891,0.0128408,0.914102,0.0000968333,0.0729495]]}
```

I tested this string [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) and it's decoding is as I wanted. But however, C# function does not work as expected.

```
    public class ServerResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string PredictImage { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string[] JSONresult { get; set; }
    }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strResponse = txtJSONstring.Text;
            ServerResponse jsonResult = new ServerResponse();
            jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(strResponse);
            txtJSONresult.AppendText(jsonResult.PredictImage);
//            txtJSONresult.AppendText(jsonResult.JSONresult);
        }
```

"jsonResult" result is null always.

Any help ?

Comment: Your `ServerResponse` object does not have the same property names as the JSON.

Comment: Oh, thanks, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want something in this format. Your names are off and the predictions with having [[]] are a list of lists.

```
public class ServerResponse
{
    public string image { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> predictions { get; set; }
}
```